# git not connecting over my work proxy

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

I want git to connect using 127.0.0.1:8080 proxy

Here is the output of `http.proxy` and `https.proxy`

```
$ git config --get http.proxy
http://127.0.0.1:8080

$ git config --get https.proxy
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

I have set up this proxy for my system and it is working with chrome, Firefox, Gradle, Android Studio. So I am sure this is correct. But git cannot fetch my code from a remote repository.

Here is the message (from SourceTree):

```
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I sure that have correct access rights.

Why git does not use that proxy?

Do I have to set proxy info for ssh, too? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why git does not use that proxy?
>   Do I have to set proxy info for ssh, too? How?

Because ssh doesn't use the *http* proxy. At all.

You can either:

- switch to an https url for your BitBucket repo,

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://<username>@bitbucket.org/<username>/myrepo.git
  ```
- or make sure that the port 22 is opened (not blocked by a firewall)

Comment: I have switched to https url.